# NotFoundError Tensorflow Text Tokenization Not Working

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp

> **Environment: Google colab**

```
!pip install -q tensorflow-text
```

> **I am Doing Text Tokenization with TensorFlow text**

```
from tensorflow_text import text
docs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([['Never tell me the odds.'], ["It's a trap!"]])
tokenizer = text.WhitespaceTokenizer()

tokenized_docs = docs.map(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x))
iterator = iter(tokenized_docs)

print(next(iterator).to_list())
print(next(iterator).to_list())
```

> **The Error I Got**

```
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-ca7b908c09b1> in <module>()
----> 1 from tensorflow_text import text
      2 docs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([['Never tell me the odds.'], ["It's a trap!"]])
      3 tokenizer = text.WhitespaceTokenizer()
      4 tokenized_docs = docs.map(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x))
      5 iterator = iter(tokenized_docs)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)

NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/_wordpiece_tokenizer.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow11ResourceMgr8DoLookupERKSsSt10type_indexS2_PPNS_12ResourceBaseE
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your Python version where Tensorflow is installed vs. what you are executing? Are both executing version 3.6?

You could try some of the suggestions at the following link:
https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/issues/293